# Is it necessary to serialize string values before producing messages in Kafka?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using the [Confluent Kafka](https://docs.confluent.io/clients-confluent-kafka-python/current/index.html) Python client and I am writing a Producer.

The value of the messages that it will produce is a string. The method [`Producer.produce()`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/#confluent_kafka.Producer.produce) accepts both `str` and `bytes` as `value`.

So, are there any benefits to serializing the string through [`StringSerializer`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/#stringserializer) before producing the message or can I just directly use the string?

Answer (score 0):

The serializer would return bytes, but you might be able to control the encoding type. If you gave a string directly, it would assume UTF8 encoding